# Use const T(&x)[N][M] to constructor class Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I don't know this question is clear or not.
I want make a simple matrix like that

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T*  m_buffer;
    int m_row;
    int m_col;
public:
    template<int N, int M>
    Matrix(const T (&x)[N][M]);
};

template<typename T>
template<int N, int M>
inline
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const T (&x)[N][M]) : m_row(N), m_col(M) {
   m_buffer = new T[N*M];
   std::copy(x, x + N*M, m_buffer);
}

int main() {
    int a[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6} };
     Matrix<int> x(a); // This not work
     return 0;
}
```

It seem be not working and get some error when compile. I want to ask how to fix this error.

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const int (*)[3]; _OI = int*]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:400:44:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const int (*)[3]; _OI = int*]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:436:45:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const int (*)[3]; _OI = int*]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:469:8:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const int (*)[3]; _OI = int*]’
../main.cpp:34:13:   required from ‘Matrix<T>::Matrix(const T (&)[N][M]) [with int N = 2; int M = 3; T = int]’
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
../main.cpp:40:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:340:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
        *__result = *__first;
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: sorry a not a1. i will repair now.

Comment: @TrungTrinh Why not post the compiler error?  Also, `std::copy` in this case requires a pointer.  You are passing a reference type to `std::copy`, not a pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Okie, i will post now.

Comment: @TrungTrinh -- So you see that the issue is with `std::copy`.  You are passing a reference to `std::copy`, and a reference cannot serve as an iterator type.  A *pointer* is required.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: how i should do?

Comment: See my answer.  When you're dealing with arrays and the algorithm functions, the algorithm functions (since they take iterators) should be provided pointers to the first and last elements.  You were passing a reference, and a reference is not a pointer.  Also, you should be using `std::vector<T> m_buffer;` instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the call to `std::copy`.  You are passing a reference as the first parameter to `std::copy`, which is not correct.  You should be passing a pointer.

To pass a pointer, the following could be done:

```
std::copy(&x[0][0], &x[0][0] + N*M, m_buffer);
```

In the above, you are passing the address of the first element in the two dimensional array, and since the data in a 2D array is contiguous, the address of one past the last element is merely specifying `N*M`.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dc7425a16023336)

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* what you're asking but using non-type template arguments, you can achieve a constructor like

```
Matrix<T,ROWS,COLS>(const T(& initializer)[ROWS][COLS])
```

allows

```
Matrix<int,2,2> a({{2,2},
                   {2,2}});
```

which has the added bonus of allowing you to enforce multiplication rules with the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// TemplateMatrix.hpp
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

template<class T, int M, int N>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T *m_buffer;
public:
    Matrix(const T matrix[M][N])
    {
        m_buffer = new T[M*N];
        memcpy(m_buffer, matrix, M*N*sizeof(T));
    }
};
```

Then, in the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "TemplateMatrix.hpp"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = {{1,1}, {2,2}};
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> m(a);
}
```